# Contemporary words used in a cultural text set in another era

Tags: terminology

Is there a term to describe the situation in which a character uses words/ expressions from other literary era eg. the story is set in 18th century and the character talks about writing a fanficton?

Comment: Alternative history, like _1632_, is full of such events, as a way to comment on cultural change, which is evident to the reader.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question of linguistics (the study of the structure and systematicity of language).

Comment: Indeed, this question belongs on English Language and Usage.

Answer (score 12):

*Anachronism.*

(This is not a specific word for what you mean, but definitely covers it).